# Bitcoin scripts with data after november 2019 Bitcoin Cash hard fork

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, smartcontracts

I am working on an application that stores metadata in the Bitcoin Cash blockchain via Bitcoin scripts. Specifically, the scripts consist of a standard multisig script followed by a data push and a data pop. For example, the following script is a 1-of-1 multisig script followed by pushing the hex encoding of { a: 'a' } and popping it off again.

```
redeemScripts OP_1 33 0x03223d34686d6f19d20519156a030f7216e5d5bd6daa9442572bbaa446d06c8dfe OP_1 OP_CHECKMULTISIG 9 0x7b2261223a2261227d OP_DROP
```

As this script is non-standard I am using p2sh and the resulting p2sh script is

```
OP_HASH160 20 0xa65dfd49f4c781dea389e485395b2e53434a34fe OP_EQUAL
```

Up until the November 2019 Bitcoin Cash hard fork the scripts worked fine but now I am getting the error message

```
16: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation). Code:-26
```

I get the same error message if I remove the push of the data and the pop. I looked at the changes to the protocol but could not figure out what I am doing wrong (https://github.com/bitcoincashorg/bitcoincash.org/blob/master/spec/2019-11-15-upgrade.md)

I would like to know how I can store metadata in Bitcoin Cash multisig script. I am aware of op_return but want to store the data in a script for reasons that go beyond this question. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like a question for ABC devs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the node I was sending the transaction to was not upgraded to the latest software. Resolved.